# Infinite loop in callback function

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!
I want to subscribe to a topic (real_position) and save these data in a variable (julio) in order to process them later in my code. I've tried to use something similar to the tutorial for the subscriber node: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29
The problem is that when I run my node, the code stacks in the callback function, repeating it again and again, until I press Ctrl + C. Then it continues with the rest of the code. Is callback function the only way to get subscribed data? and if it is, how can I make it run once per loop and get the data to a variable?
I am new to ROS and Python, and I apologize if this sounds trivial.
I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Python 2.7.12 and ROS Kinetic. Thank you in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rospy
import serial
import time
from std_msgs.msg import String

rospy.init_node('serial_connection', anonymous = True)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
print (ser.name)
time.sleep(2)

x_d = 0 # mm
y_d = 1000
thita_d = 0 # moires i rads

camera = [0, 0, 0]
error = [0, 0, 0]
sending_data = [0, 0, 0]
print(sending_data)

def callback(data):
    print("callback")
    global camera
    camera = data
    print(camera)
    print("emeina mes to callback kollimeno")

rospy.Subscriber('real_position', String, callback)
rate = rospy.Rate(1) #isws na min xreiazetai


def camera_feedback():
    print("camera feedback")
    print(camera)

def error_calculation():
    print("error caclulation")
    error[0] = x_d - camera[0]
    error[1] = y_d - camera[1]
    error[2] = thita_d - camera[2]

def controller_equations():
    print("controller equations")
    if error != [0, 0, 0]:
        print(error)
        global sending_data
        print(sending_data)
        sending_data[0] = 8
        sending_data[1] = 8
        sending_data[2] = 0

    else:
        sending_data = [0, 0, 0]
    print(error)
    print('kokos')
    print(sending_data)


def serial_connection():
    print("serial connection")
    if not rospy.is_shutdown():      
        if ser.isOpen():
            print ("Port Open")
            for i in range(1):               
                ser.write(bytes(sending_data) + '\n')
                time.sleep(0.001)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            print("in the while loop")
            camera_feedback()
            error_calculation()
            controller_equations()
            serial_connection()
            rate.sleep()
        ser.close()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309125/infinite-loop-in-callback-function/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your program structure needs a bit of a change so that it will do what you want. Here are some points:

- You should initialise your node and
  create your subscribers once only.
- The `rospy.spin()` function will spin
  forever until you close the node down
  manually.

Bearing these in mind you will need to change your code so that inside main you initialise your node once and create the subscriber once. Then you'll need to create the `rospy.Rate` object. Finally still within main you'll need to add your while loop.

This while loop will include the `rate.sleep()` to keep it at the desired frequency. Within this loop you can call your error function, control function and finally your serial connection.

Note, the body of the while loop may well execute before the callback function so you'll have to make sure your code is safe to do this.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

Just a style node for you code. You should generally make the start point of code within main, at the moment you do all your initialisation in the global scope of the script before main is reached. Although this will work it's not considered good practice. If you move the following lines and place them between `try:` and the `while` statement in main it will tidy this up.

```
rospy.init_node('serial_connection', anonymous = True)

print (ser.name)
time.sleep(2)

print(sending_data)

rospy.Subscriber('real_position', String, callback)
rate = rospy.Rate(1) #isws na min xreiazetai
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-22**:
There ought to be a notification that someone else is typing up an answer...

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-22**:
I couldn't agree more :-)

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-11-23**:
@lucasw @PeteBlackerThe3rd thank you for your response. I made some changes following your advice and I updated my code on this post. I am not sure about the position of rospy.Subscriber and rospy.rate. I tried to put it right after rospy.init but I got a callback not defined error....

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-11-23**:
...The result now looks ok. Can you tell me if these changes correspond to the tips you gave me? Just to make sure that I got it correctly.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-23**:
Yes that's what I was thinking. I'll update my answer with a few style points. But what you've got should work.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-11-26**:
I made the changes you pointed out and the node looks to work fine. Thank you for the help!